# Calculating 12v Battery Ah

Tags: batteries, amperage, ac-dc, ampere-hour

Forgive the ignorance here, electricity is a weak point of mine and I'm trying to wrap my head around it all.

I'm trying to find out how many Ah exist in an old lead acid battery. I hooked up an inverter (500W) and a power strip with x3 150W lightbulbs (So 450W total) and hooked up a rPi to monitor the voltage. That setup ran for about ~7hrs (I know its not good to run these batteries to zero but its for science!).

I'm getting caught up between AC watts and DC watts, and possibly approaching this whole problem wrong. Using [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/electric/Watt_to_Amp_Calculator.html) calculator, 3 phase AC, 3150 Watts, 110V, with power factor of 1 yeilds ~16A, where as DC, 3150 Watts, 12V yeilds ~262A. So did I pull 16 amps or 262 amps out of this thing? Not trying to be super precise but rather that life this 200Ah battery still has.

Thanks for any feedback!

Edit 1
[Inverter Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086SSRRZ7)

Edit 2
Here is the graph of the voltage over time, any idea what in the world its doing in the second half?
[image]

Comment: is your inverter producing 3 phase AC or a single phase?

Comment: @HermanZahid Good question! I guess I assumed 3 phase, but is there a way I can look it up and see? this is the amazon link [link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B086SSRRZ7/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: Measuring capacity with large discharge currents is not the best way to get an accurate capacity measurement (it tends to underestimate the actual capacity). Except of course if the battery will be subject to large currents during normal use.

Comment: @KennyRead its a single phase inverter outputting 110v. Also normal power factor is around 0.8 in most homes. You are assuming close to ideal operation right now..

Comment: @KennyRead are the light bulb in series or parallel?

Comment: @HermanZahid All the bulbs were plugged into a powerstrip pluged into the inverter

Comment: Thanks @StarCat, thats a good point! Maybe more tests are in order, but a friend of mine had thought this battery was dead and needed to be recycled and wanted to know if this had half capacity, quarter capacity, etc etc.

Comment: @HermanZahid Load is incandescent lamps. PF = 1.0

Comment: First, "110V" is just a slang term like "Kleenex". Mains voltage has undergone several small bumps since starting at 100V, and when Tesla won the war of the currents and electricity was marketed to regular folks, it happened to be at 110V.  Now it's at 120V.  Note that cheap 500W consumer-tier inverters are NOT 3-phase.  Note that 120V is 10 times 12V.  That makes the math simple.  Now you can just divide like a normal person lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three bulbs rated 150W each.  That's a load of 450W.

It ran for 7 hours.

That's 7h*450W = 3150Wh (that's watt hours.)

That's approximately how much energy your bulbs consumed.

Your battery had to supply at least 3150Wh to the inverter.

At a nominal 12 volts, 3150Wh is 262 ampere hours.  Watts are volts times amperes, so when you divide the Wh by volts, you get ampere hours.

---

That is only approximate.

- The battery voltage isn't constant while discharging.
- The current isn't constant while discharging.
- The inverter wastes a lot of power, maybe as much as 50 percent.

Given your data, you can't get a better value.

A better value would require measuring the current from the battery, the voltage from the battery, and the time.

You would measure current and voltage periodically.  Say, once a second.

For each second, you multiply the volts and the amperes to get watts, then multiply by 1 second to get watt seconds.

When the battery is fully discharged, you sum up all the watt seconds and convert to watt hours.

That result is the energy that your battery had in it.  Energy content is the interesting thing.

Most people don't deal with watt hours, though.  Batteries are rated in ampere hours, with the assumption of a nominal 12 volts.

You could either divide your watt hours by 12 volts to get an ampere hour rating, or you can sum up the current measurements every second to get ampere seconds then convert to ampere hours.

That will get you a somewhat more accurate measure of the capacity of your battery.

Regardless, you will never get a completely accurate measurement of the capacity.

The measured capacity will vary depending on the load, the temperature, how well charged the battery was, how old the battery is, and probably a bazillion other details.

What matters for hobby use is that you test it under conditions similar to the ones you will use (similar load and temperature) so that you can see how long your device will run using the given battery.

---

If your battery was rated for 200Ah when new, then you've got something wrong with your setup.

Looking at your discharge curve, I'd say you should have stopped at about 200 minutes.  You shouldn't discharge a 12V battery below about 10.5V.

200 minutes is about 3.3 hours.  That makes your rating more along the lines of (262Ah * 3.3/7) = 124 Ah.

Your test isn't really comparable to the original rating, and there's no telling what test conditions were used to determine that original rating.

---

The crazy, squiggly voltage line in the second half of the chart is your poor battery and the inverter doing their best to provide a constant 110VAC to the light bulbs, and failing.

To get the output voltage up, the inverter has to draw more current.  Drawing more current makes the voltage drop more, so the inverter draws more current.  At some point, the current draw is so high and the battery voltage so low that the inverter gives up and shuts off.

When the inverter shuts off, the battery voltage recovers, and the inverter kicks in again.  Keep repeating load, shutoff, recover, load until somebody takes pity on the poor battery and disconnects the inverter.

Comment: Thank you so much for being so thourough! I'll try to get my pi set up to measure some current and repeat!

Comment: Good analysis especially of the odd behaviour on the RHS.

Comment: @KennyRead  also the inverter is a constant power load, so when the battery voltage drops, it sucks more current to make up for the voltage drop, so this means that  the battery drains even faster.

Answer (score 1):

First please try to be careful about the difference between amperes and ampere hours, watts and watt hours.

> 3 phase AC

Nothing in your system appears to be 3 phase, but let's assume that's irrelevant beyond perhaps the immediately next mistake:

> 3150 Watts, 110V, with power factor of 1 yeilds ~16A

No, 3150 Watt **hours** yields 16 amp **hours**.  Except it's actually 28, not 16.

> where as DC

There inverter will have an efficiency of less than 100%, but let's set that aside for the moment

> 3150 Watts, 12V yeilds ~262A.

You mean 262 amp **hours**.

> So did I pull 16 amps or 262 amps out of this thing? Not trying to be super precise but rather that life this 200Ah battery still has.

No, you probably didn't pull 262 amp **hours** out of an already "old" 200 Ah battery.

Something in your setup is not as believed.

For example, perhaps those are not 150 watt lights, but 150 "watt equivalent" CFL or LED sources which actually draw a fraction as much power.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and I appreciate the feedback, my ingorance is already showing. The one thing I can tell you is they are definitely 150W incandensent lightbulbs (hot as hell!) and my battery ran 3 of those for 7hrs plugged into an inverter (link in description) how can I calculate the Ah of the battery? Thanks!

Comment: Measure the current somewhere, but carefully!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an inverter efficiency of 90%, the input would be 450/0.9 = 500 W. At 12 V the input current would be 500/12 = 41.7 A.

Typical discharge characteristics of a 12V 200 Ah battery would be as shown in the chart.

[image]

No way for even a new, top condition, fully charged battery to source 41.7 A continuously for 7 hours!

With a depleting battery the inverter output would have progressively reduced. A true picture of the actual load over 7 hours would have emerged had the inverter output voltage and current been continuously monitored.